# Regex to get multiple not kebab-case styled strings

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex pattern to match all the strings from the html-class attribute which are not (!) styled with kebab-case (e.g. class="wrongStyledClass").

My current regex is this one:

```
/class="([^a-z].*?|[a-z0-9-]+?-|[a-z0-9-]*?([^a-z0-9-\n\r"]+?[a-z0-9-]*?)+?)"/g
```

It works fine for a single class, but one thing which is still missing here is the whitespaces between multiple classes. They should be allowed, for example, this one should be valid:

```
class="this-one-is-correct icon good-one"
```

I would be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the class contains only lowercase chars, digits or `-` you could use a negative lookahead to assert not that format.

If the assertion is true, you can match all till the closing `"`

```
class="(?!\s*[a-z0-9]+(?:[\s-][a-z0-9]+)*\s*")[^"]+"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FE5wl9/1)

If you want to match an uppercase  chat between the double quotes:

```
class="[^"]*[A-Z][^"]+"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zR53B8/1)